# [Vue warn]: The .native modifier for v-on is only valid on components but it was used on <div>

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using the calendar component of Vuetify, it is showing the data properly, however I get that warning in console, it's a bit annoying and i don't know what's wrong since most of the code is a copy from the documentation, so probably it's a new bug or something?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
        today: '2020-01-01',
        events: [{
          name: 'test',
          start: '2020-01-01 10:00'
        },
        {
          name: 'test_2',
          start: '2020-02-12 10:00'
        }],
    }
  },



})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
        <v-sheet height="400">
            <v-calendar ref="calendar" :now="today" :value="today" :events="events" color="amber" event-color="amber" type="month"></v-calendar>
        </v-sheet>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a Vuetify bug. I suggest you follow this issue ~ https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/9999

Comment: I am pretty sure the solution is to upgrade your vuetify version. But good question none-the-less! I have the same problem and we don't have the time yet to upgrade Vuetify.